# Easy way to copy object values across to an object of another type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-4.0

I have been looking to make my application a little more scalable by specifying a base data model which I intend to act as a container so that the data sent through to another application is always of the correct structure.

However I want to be able to easily load data from sources such as XML and databases in the future, so I was wondering how to go about copying the values of one object to the base data model object, where the object im copying the values from may not be of the same structure (so I mainly just want to match up property names).

Here is what I tried:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> ObjectValues(object source)
    {
        if(source == null)
            return null;

        Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in source.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            try
            {
                object value = propInfo.GetValue(source, null);
                properties.Add(propInfo.Name, value);
                if (!value.GetType().IsPrimitive && !value.GetType().IsValueType)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> internalProperties = ProxyValues(value);
                    if (internalProperties != null)
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> internalProp in internalProperties)
                            properties.Add(String.Format("{0}.{1}", propInfo.Name, internalProp.Key), internalProp.Value);
                }
            }
            catch (TargetParameterCountException) { }
        }
        return properties;
    }
```

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Data Model and Reflection will work if your data are heavy objects. If you rely on a lot of simple data such as tens of thousands of strings or integers, you will notice performance degradation because of reflection.

Comment: If I'm reading this right You have a `BasePocoClass` that has a defined structure, and you want to convert that into `PocoClass1`, `PocoClass2` and `PocoClassX` which all have different structures?

Comment: @Marino Simic its about 50/50, plenty of complex types and plenty of simple types.

Comment: @Alastair Pitts Pretty much, except in reverse, I want to convert down to my defined structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you probably want to look at something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

You set up configurations:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TypeA, TypeB>().ForMember(dest => dest.PropB, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PropA));
```

Which will create a mapping from TypeA to TypeB, where the property PropA will be copied to PropB. Then when you want to use the mapping:

```
TypeA a = new TypeA();
TypeB b = new TypeB();

Mapper.Map(a, b);
```

Mapping configurations can even use custom resolvers, so if you want to do complex work when copying, you can.

There is also [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/), which some people prefer over AutoMap

Answer (score 4):

Try AutoMapper. It maps disparate types that have matching property names and also has several methods that take in expressions to customize mappings

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. What you can do is use [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to extend the base type `object` with a `merge` function. This sort of thing is relatively trivial to write yourself. Here is one i use:

```
/// <summary>
/// Merges the equivalent properties from the source to this object.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Any reference type.</typeparam>
/// <param name="destination">This object, which receives the values.</param>
/// <param name="source">The source object that the values are taken from.</param>
public static void MergeFrom<T>(this object destination, T source)
{
    Type destinationType = destination.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = source.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
    {
        PropertyInfo destinationPropertyInfo = destinationType.GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (destinationPropertyInfo != null)
        {
            if (destinationPropertyInfo.CanWrite && propertyInfo.CanRead && (destinationPropertyInfo.PropertyType == propertyInfo.PropertyType))
            {
                object o = propertyInfo.GetValue(source, null);
                destinationPropertyInfo.SetValue(destination, o, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to use it is quite simple:

```
obj1.MergeFrom(obj2);
```

will merge the like properties from `obj2` back into `obj1`, using only equivalent property names and types. Note the lack of exception handling - this is on purpose, if it fails then i want to know about it rather than handling and swallowing exceptions.

You can also take this concept and put it directly on a `Dictionary<string, object>` either as a `MergeFrom`, or as a `LoadFrom`, extension methods give you quite a bit of flexibility.